# AnnotationException: Unable to map collection

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am writing an online store using `Spring Boot` and `hiberbate`. I have an `Order` class where I need a `Сart` link with relationhip `@OneToMany`. I created all tables and created all the fields I needed. Added links to Java-code but still throws an error. I can't understand what's the matter.
I can't figure out where I made a mistake in the mapping. Could this error be related to something else?

Class Cart:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(Cart.CartId.class)
@Table(name = "cart_products")
public class Cart {

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CartId implements Serializable {

        private Long orderIds;

        private Long drinkIds;
    }


    // Fields
    //
    @Id
    private Long orderIds;

    @Id
    private Long drinkIds;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Drink drink;

    private int count;
}
```

Class Order:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_order")
public class Order {

    // Fields
    //
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private Date dateOrder;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @Column(name = "total_cost")
    private BigDecimal totalCost;

    // Relationships
    //
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id", referencedColumnName = "drink_id")
    })
    private Set<Cart> cart;
}
```

[image]

[image]

ERRORS:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countriesRepository' defined in ru.coffeetearea.repository.catalog.CountriesRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection ru.coffeetearea.model.Order.cart
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:621) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTearea.main(CoffeeTearea.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection ru.coffeetearea.model.Order.cart
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection ru.coffeetearea.model.Order.cart
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1690) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:929) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:845) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:784) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1705) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1654) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1217) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1248) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: order_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pg_order) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:832) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1680) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: order_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pg_order) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha5.jar:6.0.0.Alpha5]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried to change in the class `Order` the relation with `Set<Cart>` to `@ManyToMany`? Because according to your DB mapping it seems to be an N:N relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong here:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id", referencedColumnName = "drink_id")
})
private Set<Cart> cart;
```

You're saying that there is both on `Order` and `Cart` table a `order_id` and `drink_id` column, which is not the case.

Actually since you have the mapping defined on the child side (where `@ManyToOne` resides), you can simply refer to that mapping on the parent side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private Set<Cart> cart;
```

Comment: `org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Support for composite foreign keys not yet implemented : ru.coffeetearea.model.Order.cart` new error